# Deleting datatable while server-side processing

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have this code:

```
$("#office-select").change(function(){
    oTable.api().ajax.reload();
});
```

where `oTable` is my datatable. Everything works, but I want the old table to be hidden while the new one is loading. There should only be a spinner shown.

I tried something along these lines:

```
$("#office-select").change(function(){
    oTable.clear();
    oTable.api().ajax.reload();
});
```

but it did not work.  Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#element)

Example:

```
$("#office-select").change(function(){
  $(<selector of your table>).block({ 
            message: '<h1>Processing</h1>', 
            css: { border: '3px solid #a00' } 
  }); 
  oTable.clear();
  oTable.api().ajax.reload();
  $(<selector of your table>).unblock();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try `oTable.clear().draw();` instead of `oTable.clear();` You need to tell the API to render the change:

```
$("#office-select").change(function(){
    oTable.clear().draw();
    oTable.api().ajax.reload();
});
```

Comment: As precised it the documentation https://datatables.net/reference/api/clear(), it will not empty the DataTable if it's server side processing.

Comment: Ahh... sorry about this oversight on my part @LucileDT -- happy to delete this answer if it is not helpful to the problem